# await on windows store app, not working as expected

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store, async-await

on a windows store project im working on i have this piece of code on the app.xaml.cs file

```
    ...          
            DoStuff();



                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage), e.Arguments);
            }
```

and on the DoStuff function after some operations, i call this other function called InsertDB.

```
    private async void InsertDB(RootObject obj)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => obj.InsereDB());
    }
```

What this one does , is insert some data into a sqlite database.
Now my problem is this, when i start my app the database starts getting filled, i can see that cause im looking at the file inside the LocalState folder of my project, and the sqlite file starts growing in size, but before it finishes getting the data inside my View("SomePage") gets loaded.

Shouldn't the await task prevent the view from loading until the "obj.InsereDB" function returns  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not waiting because `InsertDB` is an `async void` method, which means, from the caller's perspective, it will run synchronously *until* it hits the first `await` keyword. Once it does, it will return to the caller.

Picture this:

```
private async void InsertDB(RootObject obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
    await Task.Run(() => obj.InsereDB());
    Console.WriteLine(2);
}

InsertDB(obj);
Console.WriteLine(3);
```

This code will print `1 3 2`. When `InsertDB` hit the `await` keyword, it returned to the caller, which printed 3. The rest of the method ran asynchronously.

You need to make `InsertDB` return a task, and await it.

```
private async Task InsertDB(RootObject obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
    await Task.Run(() => obj.InsereDB());
    Console.WriteLine(2);
}

await InsertDB(obj);
Console.WriteLine(3);
```

This will print `1 2 3`

Comment: ah, yes that seems to work better indeed , even wrote the Debug.WriteLine() to see it, and it does print 1 2 3 , but , my inicial "problem" still maintains, it still loads the view before the task ends.

Comment: @Ric you'll have to await `DoStuff` as well

Comment: yeah eheh, i noticed right before you answered eheh , thanks for the help :)